# How to combine multiple arbitrary values such as :has in Tailwind

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a problem where I want an element to not show, if it has children.

In plain CSS this is:

```
&:not(:has(*)){
 display: none
}
```

However, in Tailwind I can not figure it out. I've tried few things such as below, but none would work:

```
[&:not(:has(*)):hidden] 

[&:not([&:has(*)]):hidden]
```

Is there a way to combine multiple arbitrary values?

Comment: Your first example is not ‘plain CSS’. Did you mean SCSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect – you'd want the class attached to the variant to be outside the square brackets:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="[&:not(:has(*))]:hidden">
  Foo
</div>

<div class="[&:not(:has(*))]:hidden">
  <div>Bar</div>
</div>
```